# "Stack ........ was corrupted" error whilst using memcpy

Tags: c++, stack, memcpy

The code below is used to extract an int and a long from a vector of chars. However, I get an error about stack corruption (see below code):

```
std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<MyClass> > foo(std::vector<char> My_Vector){
    std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<MyClass> > y;

    long p;
    int q;
    long pp;
    int qq;

    //pp is being set to the value of bytes 26 to 33 from My_Vector
    memcpy( &pp, &My_Vector[25], 8);
    memcpy( &qq, &My_Vector[19], 4);

    q = qq;
    p = static_cast<double>(pp)/1E8;

    boost::shared_ptr<MyClass> x(new MyClass(p,q));
    y.push_back(x);

    return y;
}
```

I get the error:

> Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'pp.51040' was
>   corrupted.

Could someone help me understand what is going wrong here please?

Comment: Are you sure that long is 8 bytes on your system ? Maybe using sizeof(long) or sizeof(pp) would be a good idea ?

Comment: Use `sizeof pp` instead of hard-coding it.

Comment: `long` is 4 bytes with MSVC.

Comment: @user997112 Thank you for using the word, whilst.  Well done.

Comment: @BitFiddlingCodeMonkey do <certain countries> "cough cough" say "while", instead?

Comment: @user997112: I believe the Yanks are among those who can't be arsed with the "st", yeah.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`My_Vector[25]` is not byte 25. It is byte 26.

Also, you have no checking that `sizeof(long) == 8`, or `sizeof(int) == 4` (in fact, this would be unusual nowadays).

Comment: Sorry that was just me confusing the byte# with the vector index- its still correct that I want My_Vec[25] to My_Vec[32]